# How can I set maximum and minimum value in the color scale of contourf ?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I set maximum and minimum value in the color scale of contourf of matplotlib?

I explain. I have a set of data and I want to put as maximum in the color scale the 95% percentile of the data.

I have tried in this way:

```
goh = colors.Normalize(0, perchi)

plt.contourf(x, y, B, norm = goh) #cmap = plt.cm.hot,

plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

but it returns to me a plot with only one color...and also the scale is monochromatic...
I want the whole color scale linear but in the range (min, perchi) and not in (min, max).
I want that the points between perchi and max are shown as if the y have perchi values...

How could I do?

Answer (score 7):

to set the maximum and minimum valued you can do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# Create fake data
B = np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=(100, 100))


plt.contourf(B, vmin=2, vmax=8)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

The values outside the range are set to the maximum and minimum.

Comment: I have done like you told me but it doesn't work...it returns to me a uniform scale of colors!(i get a whole red plot!)
I want that the scale of colors remain the one in the not modified plot!

Comment: Try to remove all arguments such as `norm, vmax`, does this behaviour persist? If it doesn't then you are setting the limits incorrectly, try printing `B.max()` and `B.min()` and compare with the limits.